# Hibernate -- argument type mismatch when setting an int as an int

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing some refactoring on a legacy application (dependency version information included below), and extracted two related fields from `Order` to a smaller class, `PriorityData`. The fields still live in the same table, but are now mapped as a `component`.
When trying to load an `Order`, I'm getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` on one of the re-mapped fields (`PriorityData.priority`).

Normally, that means a simple type screw-up, but I've checked it several times and am coming up blank as to the cause. The mapping looks correct to me, the database types are correct, etc. Looking for a resolution, or at least a hint as to what I should examime.

The updated `Order` hbm mapping snippet is below:

Accessors from `Order`:

```
public PriorityData getPriorityData() {
    return this.priorityData;
}

public void setPriorityData(PriorityData priorityData) {
    this.priorityData = priorityData;
}
```

Accessors from `PriorityData`:

```
public int getPriority() {
    return this.priority;
}

public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public Timestamp getPriorityChangeDate() {
    return priorityChangeDate;
}

public void setPriorityChangeDate(Timestamp priorityChangeDate) {
    this.priorityChangeDate = priorityChangeDate;
}
```

Database type declarations:

```
PRIORITY: INTEGER 
PRIORITY_CHANGE_DATE: TIMESTMP
```

Dependencies: Spring 3.2.8, Hibernate 3.5, DB2 9.5

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-6] BasicPropertyAccessor.set(118) | IllegalArgumentException in class: com.foo.bar.PriorityData, setter method of property: priority
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-6] BasicPropertyAccessor.set(122) | expected type: int, actual value: java.lang.Boolean
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-6] OrderQueueServiceImpl.getOrderLockStatus4Edit(6251) | Error while updating lock status
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.foo.bar.PriorityData.priority; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.foo.bar.PriorityData.priority
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:1007)
    at com.foo.bar.dao.foodb.impl.hibernate.OrderQueueDAOImpl.findOrderDetailByOrderId(OrderQueueDAOImpl.java:105)
    at com.foo.bar.service.impl.OrderQueueServiceImpl.findOrderDetailByOrderId(OrderQueueServiceImpl.java:157)
    at com.foo.bar.service.impl.OrderQueueServiceImpl.getOrderLockStatus4Edit(OrderQueueServiceImpl.java:6226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.getOrderLockStatus4Edit(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.bar.service.proxy.OrderQueueServiceProxy.getOrderLockStatus4Edit(OrderQueueServiceProxy.java:488)
    at com.foo.bar.web.server.OrderServiceImpl.getEditOrderData(OrderServiceImpl.java:898)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at com.foo.bar.web.mvc.GWTSpringController.handleRequest(GWTSpringController.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.foo.bar.web.servlet.GwtCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GwtCacheControlFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.foo.bar.PriorityData.priority
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.setPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.deepCopy(TypeFactory.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:773)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$34.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$34.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:407)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:66)
    ... 107 more
```

Comment: Please check the datatype and mapping, though you said you have already done that, the log told us different story: class: com.foo.bar.PriorityData, setter method of property: priority expected type: int, actual value: java.lang.Boolean

Comment: First two lines of the log are giving a hint about the problem, please check the datatypes of priority in the database, in java file and where it is being set.

Comment: That's what's so bizarre to me; I double-checked just now, (I also posted the getters/setters and database column types, taken right from a query against db2's syscolumns) and everything's an int. The field in question was also an int before it was extracted to the PriorityData class.

Comment: Naturally, it turned out to be something simple and kind of stupid. Someone else on the team wrote this before going on vacation, and since I'd just picked it up, I didn't notice that the class also contained a boolean method named isPriority(). Hibernate was picking that method to set based on bean naming conventions instead of of setPriority(int).